# Bundle wiring is no longer valid for Pax-Exam probe

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, pax-exam

I developed a perfectly working test in Pax-Exam 4.8.0 and Karaf 4.0.3: I recently upgraded both Pax-Exam and Karaf and now I'm trying to debug a quite obscure error I get with **Pax-Exam 4.9.1** and **Karaf 4.0.6**.

#### You can find a self contained example of this problem [here](https://github.com/mrulli/com.flairbit.osgi.paxexam-issue).

In my junit class I inject the following field:

```
@RunWith(PaxExam.class)
@ExamReactorStrategy(PerClass.class)
public class CustomerMockDBGeneratorTest extends TestCase {

    @Inject
    private static LogService log;

    @Inject
    private static BundleContext bcontext;

    ...


    @Test
    public void createMockDataBase() {
        // customerMockDBGeneratorTest.java:142 in the stacktrace below:
        ServiceReference<CustomerUserStorageService> ustoreservice = 
            bcontext.getServiceReference(CustomerUserStorageService.class); 
        ...
```

apparently the Pax-Exam probe is invalidated for some reasons and in my `@Test` method above I get the following error as soon as I use the bundle context to get a reference to the `CustomerUserStorageService` service:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class 'com.example.customer.storage.users.api.customerUserStorageService' because the bundle wiring for PAXEXAM-PROBE-a1ea3766-7d38-4fc2-b3eb-e33192ab8993 is no longer valid.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1539)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.example.customer.storage.provider.customerMockDBGeneratorTest.createMockDataBase(customerMockDBGeneratorTest.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChild(ContainerTestRunner.java:68)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChild(ContainerTestRunner.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.invokeViaJUnit(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:124)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.findAndInvoke(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:97)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.call(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.rbc.internal.RemoteBundleContextImpl.remoteCall(RemoteBundleContextImpl.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I honestly have no clue of why the probe bundle gets invalidated: why this could happen? Anyone experienced a similar situation?

**The very same code is working fine with Pax-Exam v 4.8.0 and Karaf 4.0.3.**

Comment: unfortunately the sample isn't as self contained. Dependencies aren't resolved and therfore can't be compiled. It also requires to have Eclipse, so it's not IDE independent ...

Comment: The project requires bndtools 3.2.0 and eclipse ide. Apart from that, deps are downloaded from maven central so they should be available. What is the missing dependency?

Comment: basically it's not working at all ...

Comment: I gave it another try, but tbh. it's rather frustrating. A clean checkout, import into eclipse (yes it required a fresh installation of it) Adding the bnd-tools (which only work with eclipse, not IDEA). The dependencies aren't resolved at all, trying to convert it into a maven project doesn't help either as the bundle for this package osgi.enroute.debug.api.Debug doesn't seem to be in maven-central. Sorry to say but this doesn't work. Please convert your issues describing sample to use maven, so everybody can work on it.